# Counting rows for all tables for a particular column and column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008 and want to get total row count of a column from all tables in a database.

here is my sample data

**Table 1**

```
T1Id       Name
1          XCV
2          ASD
3          GHJ
```

**Table 2**

```
  T2Id      T1Id       Name
  1         1          TYU
  2         1          BBB
  3         2          LLL
  4         1          JJJ
  5         1          LKM
  6         2          POI
```

**Table 3**

```
  T3Id      T1Id       Name
  1         3          DDS
  2         3          BSS
  3         2          SQA
  4         2          FWF
  5         1          IKM
  6         2          PLO
```

I have Table4 also but don't want to add in result count

I am trying

```
    SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT ta.name AS TableName, SUM(pa.rows) AS RowCnt
FROM         sys.tables AS ta LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      sys.partitions AS pa ON pa.object_id = ta.object_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      sys.schemas AS sc ON ta.schema_id = sc.schema_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS ON ta.name = INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME
WHERE     (ta.is_ms_shipped = 0) AND (pa.index_id IN (1, 0)) AND (INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME = N'T1Id') AND 
                      (ta.name <> N'Table4')
GROUP BY sc.name, ta.name
HAVING      (SUM(pa.rows) > 0)
ORDER BY RowCnt DESC
```

Above SQL giving me result

```
 TableName    RowCnt
 XCV          5
 ASD          5
 GHJ          2
```

but I want to get only XCV (Table1 and T1Id = 1) records counts .
How to do this with above query or any other suggestion ?

Expected result

```
 Name    RCount
 XCV     5
```

Edit :

I have more then 200 tables in my database and it have T1Id in All tables,
my aim to find the count of T1Id = 1 from All tables and I dont want to include Table 4 in Results.

Comment: You want to get the one with the max records? This is why the expected result is XCV in your example? Or you always want XCV as result?

Comment: And why `top (100) percent`? it completely meaningless... perhaps you want `top 1`? Your question is not very clear. please try to describe your goal better.

Comment: I want Only T1Id Records from All Table and not include Table4

Comment: top (100) percent is adding SQL Management studio by default..

Comment: Shouldn't it be `ASD = 5` too?

Comment: @SouravA , yes, corrected.

Comment: Why can't you just add the condition ... `TA.Object_ID = 1` along with the query? Or in you case.. `TA.T1ID = 1`?

Comment: @souravA that the question where to add TA.T1ID = 1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83829/discussion-between-sourava-and-khan-imran-ali).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to 'generically' find all values in any table column named `T1Id` with a value of `1` (except for `Table4`, and I guess you'll want to exclude `Table1` row counts as well, as this seems to be the 'master' reference table of column value-name mappings).

AFAIK you will need to resort to dynamic Sql in order to apply the filter.

Unfortunately [your sample query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7227c/4) is misleading - the query actually returns

```
Table2  6
Table3  6
Table1  3
```

Which are the overall rowcounts of the tables obtained from `sys.partitions.rows`  (i.e. not filtered in anyway).

I believe the approach needed is, after finding the 'Eligible' Tables containing the column of interest, what you need to be doing is actually querying each table, and then filtering each with your required predicate (i.e. `T1ID = '1'`). You then need to sum up all of these results to project your final result.

My solution is too horrid to contemplate posting here, but I've put up a [Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7227c/3) and its on a [Gist Here](https://gist.github.com/nonnb/68336e6d94b0ba8ce735). Basically, it generates the following dynamic Sql:

```
WITH summedCte AS 
( 
    SELECT T1ID, COUNT(*) AS RowInTable  FROM [dbo].[Table2] GROUP BY T1ID  
    UNION ALL  
    SELECT T1ID, COUNT(*) AS RowInTable  FROM [dbo].[Table3] GROUP BY T1ID 
)
SELECT T.Name, t.T1Id, SUM(c.RowInTable) AS RowsInAllTables
    FROM summedCte c
    INNER JOIN Table1 t
      on c.T1Id = t.T1Id
    WHERE t.Name = 'XCV'
    GROUP BY t.Name, t.T1Id;
```

Which you can obviously tailor to meet your predicate needs.

**Edit - Caveat**

After seeing the OP's comment, viz that the intended usage is to enforce a 'may not delete if in parent row is in use' business rule in an application, it is clear that use of a cursor and loop is not fit for production.

The preferred approach should be along the lines of an ORM or other productivity tool:

- Use the dynamic sql hack to build the CTE based query (i.e. instead of `sp_executesql @sql`, simply print `@sql` and grab the resultant SQL)
- The resultant CTE (`UNION` of ~200 tables) can then be baked into your application to enforce the business rule.
- However, each time any relevant database DDL is changed, then the CTE will need to be regenerated and re-absorbed into the app e.g. a build could be avoided e.g. by retaining the CTE query as a tokenized script.

Comment: please see edit... your answer will find count only from table1

Comment: To confirm - once you have found all tables with a column named `T1ID` (except for Table4) you then want to apply a summed select of the count of all rows in all such tables grouped by `T1ID` and joined back to `T1ID` so that you can apply `Table1.Name`?

Comment: my query is fulling my requirement ,My aim is to show table name of a database with T1Id count. as showing in my qurey but i just want to add column value condition in query. like T1Id = 1 or 2 or 3 ... so on.

Comment: The problem here is that you actually need to (dynamically) go into the tables to get grouped counts by `T1ID` for each - the informational DMVs aren't going to give you this. Also, I'm guessing you want to exclude the row counts from `Table1` as well, given that it is just a reference / lookup table?

Comment: I give you actual situation, I am working on inventory project , where i have product, sales, and purchase tables have present with ProductId, with one flag _FlagName, when User will delete a product I want to check is there productId is in use in sales or purchase with _FlagName = 1 , so then i will show a massage like sale product Id cout = 10 and purchase  product Id cout = 10, you can not delete this product.

Comment: If there are a finite number of tables that you know are dependent / foreign keyed (and potentially cascaded) on a particular column, I would suggest just doing a simple query (`WHERE EXISTS`, or a `JOIN` and check the row count) which directly checks the known tables for the deletion rule, rather than resorting to a generic solution using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` et al - it will be much simpler. I've posted a generic dynamic sql solution in any event.

Comment: Yes but it have more then 200 tables i gives you only product example my aim to make function that only pass table id and table name it will check it and give count

Comment: In which case, have you looked [at the fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7227c/3)?